# Expose locally cached images via Docker registry

Tags: docker

I have a Docker installation with several images (some locally built, and others pulled from remote repositories). I also have a Docker registry instance running locally.

Is there a way to expose the images already available in my Docker installation via my registry instance, without re-tagging and pushing each of them to my registry (as suggested by Docker's guide to deploying a registry server, at https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)?

From what I understood via the above guide, the registry instance uses its own storage area (volume) on the local disk. I was perhaps thinking that I could mount the local image cache (residing somewhere inside `/var/lib/docker`) to the registry container instead of its default volume, or do some kind of symlinking 'hack' to achieve the same effect.

Any insight on a possible solution is more than welcome, regardless of how 'hacky' it might seem :)